# Find all $g(t)$ such that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(t)\sin(n t)dt=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Find all $g(t)$ such that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(t)\sin(n t)dt=0$ for all $n=1,2,3...$.

Obvious if $g(t)=g(-t)$, those $g(t)$ are satisfy.

If $g(t)$ is non-zero even function, then we need find $g(t)$ such that $\int_0^\pi g(t)sin(nt)=0$, is it even possible ?

Comment: What are the conditions on $g(t)$? If it is only riemann integrable then it is false. Take $g$ to be $1$ at exactly one point and zero everywhere else.

Comment: you can write $g$ as a Fourier series, and see what conditions the coefficients have to match.

Comment: Each function can be decomposed as a sum of an odd and an even function. Now that you know that the even composant does not affect the value of the integral...

Answer (score 1):

If you want continuous functions $g(t)$...

*Hint*: As nicomezi said, every function is sum of even and odd function. So, it is enough to assume that if $g(t)$ is odd and satisfies the above property, then $g(t) = 0$.

By  Stone–Weierstrass theorem, real trigonometric polynomials are dense in $C[-\pi, \pi]$ w.r.t. the uniform norm. Now since $g(t)$ is odd, it can be approximated by a sequence of odd trigonometric polynomials $p_n(t)$, which involves only terms in $\sin(rt)$.

By hypothesis, $\int g(t) p_n(t) = 0$. So, $$0 = \lim _{n \to \infty} \int g(t) p_n(t) = \int  \lim _{n \to \infty} g(t) p_n(t) = \int (g(t))^2.$$

So $g(t) = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Moreover, can we conclude that $g(t)=0,a.e.$?

Comment: Yeah, use that a Riemann integrable function on a compact interval is continuous a.e.. The same proof works then, and in the end from $\int (g(t))^2 = 0$ conclude that $g$ is zero a.e.